# Sharepoint 2007 list alerts

Tags: 2007, list, alert

I have a SharePoint list for which I have created a specific view with a filtered column.

I have set an alert to alert me if `"Existing items are modified"` and `"Someone changes an item that appears in the following view:"` with the name of my view.

But the alert activates on any changes to the list, not just the specified view. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Configure alerts per [SPView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.aspx) basis is not supported in SharePoint.

But it could be simulated, for example via workflows. 
Below is demonstrated how to create workflow for sending notifications via email in SPD.

1. Create List Workflow
2. Specify Start Option "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" in Workflow Settings
3. Create workflow as shown below on picture
   [image]